# Windows Media player isn't seeing some sub folders

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

I'm trying to share some video files from my computer to my Roku 3 via it's media player app. To do this I have to use Windows Media Player on the computer.

Rather than add all of my video files (the UI on the Roku isn't the best), I'm only sharing the specific folders with videos I want to watch now. The folder structure is like this:

```
Main
 |--- Folder A
 |       |--- Sub Folder 1
 |       |--- Sub Folder 2
 |
 |--- Folder B
 |       |--- Sub Folder 3
 |       |--- Sub Folder 4
```

and so on.

I've added `Folder A` and `Folder B` to the media player library, but only files in `Sub Folder 1` and `Sub Folder 4` have shown up. I have tried removing and re-adding the folders, adding the sub folders explicitly, resetting the media library and nothing seems to work.

As far as I can see the only difference between the folders that appear and the ones that don't is the presence of a `Thumbs.db` file in the ones that do.

So what do I have to get Windows Media Player to see the files in these folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the files it can't see are .mkv files which presumably Windows Media Player can't play, rather than .mp4 files, which it can.

This would explain the lack of a `Thumbs.db` file as well.

It does mean that I'm probably not going to be able to view these files on the Roku :(

Comment: See http://superuser.com/a/786947/137371 for a way to include MKV files in WMP's library.